# Dynamically choose number of lines per page in the pagination section

Tags: javascript, react-admin

I want to add the ability to change the perPage option value in each pagination section of my List components.
I created a CustomPagination component based on [@material-ui/core's TablePagination component](https://material-ui.com/api/table-pagination/) to allow to do this but 2 problems appear :

- The displayed range is positioned on the 2nd page instead of the first. It is impossible to access the first page by clicking on the previous page button
- If I change the value of the perPage drop-down list: nothing happens, the onChangeRowsPerPage method is correctly called but it seems that the setPerPage function does nothing. On the other hand if I click on next page then the table is correctly displayed with the number of lines corresponding to the selected choice, strange. Still unable to access the first page of the table also

Below is the code of my PostList.js component :

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import React from 'react';
import {
  Datagrid,
  List,
  Responsive,
  ShowButton,
  SimpleList,
  TextField
} from 'react-admin';

import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import ChevronLeft from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRight from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
import { Toolbar, ToolbarGroup } from 'material-ui/Toolbar';
import TablePagination from '@material-ui/core/TablePagination';

const CustomPagination = ({ page, perPage, total, setPage, setPerPage 
}) => {
const nbPages = Math.ceil(total / perPage) || 1;

const handleChangeRowsPerPage = event => {
    perPage = event.target.value;
    setPerPage(perPage);
};

const handleChangePage = (event, page) => {
    page < nbPages && page > 0 && setPage(page);
};

return (
    nbPages > 1 && (
        <TablePagination
            component="span"
            count={total}
            rowsPerPage={perPage}
            page={page}
            backIconButtonProps={{
                'aria-label': 'Previous Page'
            }}
            nextIconButtonProps={{
                'aria-label': 'Next Page'
            }}
            onChangePage={handleChangePage}
            labelRowsPerPage="Lignes par page"
            rowsPerPageOptions={[2, 5, 10, 50, 100]}
            onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
        />
      )
    );
};

const styles = theme => ({
  title: {
    maxWidth: '20em',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap'
  }
});

const PostList = withStyles(styles)(({ classes, ...props }) => (
  <List
    {...props}
    sort={{ field: 'published_at', order: 'DESC' }}
    perPage={2}
    pagination={<CustomPagination />}
  >
    <Responsive
        small={
            <SimpleList
                linkType="show"
                primaryText={record => record.title}
            />
        }
        medium={
            <Datagrid>
                <TextField source="id" />
                <TextField source="title" cellClassName={classes.title} />
                <ShowButton />
            </Datagrid>
        }
    />
  </List>
));

export default PostList;
```

And [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/7zy0n450vx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be provided by default in the upcoming `2.3` version. See this pull request for details: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/2173

Comment: For further readers, the `react-admin@2.3.0` is now available https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/releases/tag/v2.3.0